# xml parsing? how to?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

how do i parse this xml data's "Question" element into an object called "question" with a string array property called "options"? I know there are lots of xml posts with answers but they all confuse me i just need one that fits my problem. There will be a total of 50 questions in the xml file, and i want to extract each question element and it's child elements and contents into a question object. i use c# on visual studio 2010.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Questions>
 <Question id ="1">
<Content>Which of the following statements represents the view expressed by the writer    in the first paragraph?</Content>
<Options>
  <A>Evil Thoughts will eventually ruin the evil man.</A>
  <B>If we do not stop the pendulum of thoughts from swinging, our thoughts will soon become our enemies.</B>
  <C>Too many evil thoughts leave fatal consequence.</C>
  <D>It is possible to decide what controls our thoughts.</D>
</Options>
</Question>
<Question id ="2">
<Content>From the argument in the second paragraph, it can be concluded that evil thoughts control the lives people who</Content>
<Options>
  <A>are helpless because they fly out of their minds</A>
  <B>cherish idle and slothful ways</B>
  <C>are thieves with evil instincts</C>
  <D>treasure and ruminate on them.</D>
</Options>
</Question>
<Question id ="3">
   <Content>The expression think of the devil and he will appear..., as used in this  passage, suggests that</Content>
 <Options>
  <A>like the devil, evil thoughts must not reign in our hearts</A>
  <B>evil thoughts are fantasies which exist only in people's minds</B>
  <C>uncontrolled evil thoughts may lead to evil deeds</C>
  <D>the devil gives evil thoughts only to those who invite him in.</D>
</Options>
</Question>
<Question id ="4">
<Content>Which of the following statements summarizes the argument of the last paragraph?</Content>
 <Options>
  <A>Heavy traffic on a miry and dirty road may lead to evil thoughts.</A>
  <B>The more evil we think, the more vile we are likely to become.</B>
  <C>Evil people should not be welcomed as guest in our homes the same way as we welcome good people.</C>
  <D>Evil thoughts control the key to the human heart and no one can keep the out.</D>
</Options>
```

Comment: Taking a little time to understand how serialisation works will mean those posts won't confuse you anymore.

Comment: what have you tried..`hireacoder` or do it yourself and comeback here if you have any trouble doing it..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with [LINQ to Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx):

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var query = xdoc.Descendants("Question")
                .Select(q => new Question()
                {
                    Id = (int)q.Attribute("id"),
                    Content = (string)q.Element("Content"),
                    Options = q.Element("Options")
                               .Elements()
                               .Select(o => (string)o).ToArray()
                });
```

This will return `IEnumerable<Question>` sequence, where Question is a class like:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string[] Options { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and not regarding my question as dumb and repetitive